# Is it ok to say 'go Amazon shopping'?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I know that we can say go grocery shopping, go clothes shopping when you want to buy groceries and clothes.

Can I say **I am gonna go Amazon shopping** when I want to buy stuff on Amazon?

(I'm not buying Amazon.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, at least, it would be understood. So, *"I'm going to go Amazon shopping"* is well understood in the *context* of buying something online. Nevertheless, *I'm going to shop **on** Amazon* would be more idiomatic.

When brands become immensely popular, anything would work! The proper nouns become verbs! In future, who knows, you may *amazon* something? The way we *google.* But mind it, you then drop the capitalization of it.

Nevertheless, if you want to use it, you may drop 'shopping' as it'd be redundant. You *google the term* rather *google search the term.*

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question. On the one hand, phrases like "to go fishing" and "to go shopping"  generally involve *going somewhere*, and shopping on Amazon can be done in pajamas, without physically going anywhere.  On the other hand, this phrase can be found in natural use on the internet.

I guess it depends on your own tolerance level for bending the rules.  A purist would avoid "to go Amazon shopping" but would be okay with other formulations, such as "to do some Amazon shopping" or "to start [or finish] one's Amazon shopping."